# How do I encrypt SQL Server data in application level and still be able to query it with LIKE?

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption

**Situation:**

- I am developing an ASP.NET website for my organization using Microsoft SQL Server and C# .NET. This will be an Intranet website.
- The MS SQL Server database contains sensitive data in some columns. There are about 320,000 rows in about 6 tables. The data is top-secret for me because I manually prepared it and entered it in tables. The mission was tedious, it took me about one year. That is said, I do NOT want anybody EVER to get a readable copy of this data.
- I do not have any permission to the Intranet server. I must give the published website and the database data and schema to someone else to host it. I will protect my .NET code.
- The department staff administering the database server will host the website. They are NOT trustful, and MUST NOT get a readable copy of the data. They have complete access and full permission to manage SQL Server.
- I need to query encrypted data with *LIKE*.
- Although stored procedures are best for me, I do not mind writing `SELECT` statements in .NET.
- The readable string is at most 100 characters long. I will encrypt it with `System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider` and store it in the database in `nvarchar(300)`. So the encrypted string stored in the database is at most 300 characters long. The LIKE pattern will not exceed 100 characters.

What I have done (please correct me if wrong):

- I considered database build-in encryption/decryption functionality. But those who have complete access to the server will be able to decrypt the data.
- I considered encrypting the data in application level, using .NET, and creating a CLR function that is callable from SQL Server. the CLR function will decrypt the data in the same SELECT statement. But How to prevent server administrators from using this CLR function to decrypt all data?

**SPECIFIC QUESTION**: what can I do to protect my data from database administrators, and still be able to query it with *LIKE*? If not possible, what is the best practice in my case? Can I prevent database server administrators from using the CLR function?

Comment: How long are the strings to be searched and how long is the like pattern? Will it be a simple substring pattern?

Comment: "best practice" would generally be not to give untrustworthy staff full access to the database.  Barring that, you can't encrypt the data in the application and do anything other than a pure equality search in the database.  You could pull all the data into your application, decrypt it there, and then do the like.  Or if you can pre-compute the subexpressions you'd want to search on in the database and denormalize the database to store those subexpressions.  Of course, that will make changing the data more difficult.

Comment: @usr, Thank you. The readable string is at most 100 characters long. I will encrypt it with System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider and store it in the database in nvarchar(300). So the encrypted string stored in the database is at most 300 characters long. The LIKE pattern will not exceed 100 characters.

Comment: @Justin-cave, Thank you very much. But can I prevent database server administrators from using the CLR function?

Comment: No.  A database administrator will be able to run any code you deploy to the database.  They should also be able to sniff any data coming from or going to the database so you can't pass unencrypted data to the client or the encryption key to the database.  I'm unclear where your encryption key is being stored and why the admins can't simply get the key from the middle tier but that's a separate question.

Comment: How is it that you're building a site that everyone in your organization will use but the organization is perfectly happy for you to build it in such a way that no one will ever be able to recover/ fix the data if you leave in the future?  Unless you assembled the data on your own time without company resources and you've signed some sort of licensing agreement with your organization, the whole approach seems pretty dubious.

Comment: @Justin-Cave, Thank you. I will make it clear. This application is mine. I have assembled the data at home, on your own time, and without company resources. I am going to develop the .NET code at home, too.  I will give it to my employer for free, I may sell it elsewhere. There are 2 types of data: one is critical for the logic but website users should not play with, it will not be shown to them, this is what I need to encrypt. The other type of data is what users add; it will be huge too, but will NOT be encrypted, Users have full access to it and they can get a readable copy of it any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For each query download all strings to the client, decrypt them and search them.
2. Or, use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption which is probably unrealistic.
3. Or, generate all possible substrings to be found by like. Encrypt them and store them. Then, you can equality match on them. For an N character string there are about N*N/2 substrings. Probably the encryption breaks down with short strings because an attacker can deduce duplicate characters and so on.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: You can run the logic with your secret data on a different box. Make an api that uses your data but doesn't expose it. This will need to be on a box you control. If that's not possible then you're SOL.

Why are you building a server application that only you can use? Why not just keep it on your desktop?

It would be better to use a desktop application to access the database versus a web server application like ASP.NET.

If you don't have total physical control over the box, and don't trust the admins, then that's a problem.

If you're storing the decryption key on the web server, then the admins will have access to it. You'll need a solution where the decryption key stays on your computer, or preferably in a smart card. You need end-to-end encryption.

You should look at something like ZeroDB, which does the above http://www.zerodb.io/

It does contains() but not LIKE. http://docs.zerodb.io/#supported-queries

Comment: Everyone in my organization will use this website not only me. Secret data  is critical for the logic, but it will not appear in website pages. Yes, I do not trust the admins reusing/stealing the secret data.